# SQL select distinct data without ordering the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have table which contains data as below:

```
DECLARE @CheckList TABLE
                   (  
                        RowNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1) INT, 
                        CheckId INT, 
                        Treat INT 
                   )  
INSERT INTO @CheckList 
VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1),
       (1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 3),
       (1, 2, 3);

SELECT DISTINCT Id, CheckId 
FROM @CheckList
WHERE Id = 1
```

Where I want to select the data from this table as

```
   Id   CheckId
   ------------
    1   1
    1   3
    1   2
```

I want the same order of the check id which is available in table. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure the second Treat set is `(1,1,1)`? or it is `(1,1,2)` ?

Comment: this is sample data but i want in same order which is available in table. i.e. 1 3 2

Comment: @Arulkumar yes unfortunately.

Comment: Are you missing a column? Your SQL is not valid. There is no `id` column? How you are inserting data in `identity` column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Retain original ordering by `RowNumber` identity column

```
select Id,CheckId
from(
   select distinct Id,CheckId, min(rownumber) over(partition by Id,CheckId) rn
   from @CheckList
   where Id=1
   ) t
order by rn;
```

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88073a5c38809dcd933997b5893612bb)

Answer (score -1):

you can check this

```
DECLARE @CheckList TABLE
               (  Id INT ,  CheckId INT, Treat INT )  
INSERT INTO @CheckList 
VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1),(1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 3),(1,3,3), (1, 2, 3);

SELECT DISTINCT Id, CheckId 
FROM @CheckList
WHERE Id = 1
```